# Python csv : use different variable name to store list then export out row by row

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Here's my python script to get sql results in postgresql,

```
import sys

#set up psycopg2 environment
import psycopg2

#driving_distance module
query = """
    select *
    from driving_distance ($$
        select
            gid as id,
            start_id::int4 as source,
            end_id::int4 as target,
            shape_leng::double precision as cost
        from network
        $$, %s, %s, %s, %s
    )
"""

#make connection between python and postgresql
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'TC_routing' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = '****'")
cur = conn.cursor()

#count rows in the table
cur.execute("select count(*) from network")
result = cur.fetchone()
k = result[0] + 1

#run loops
rs = []
i = 1
while i <= k:
    cur.execute(query, (i, 1000000, False, False))
    rs.append(cur.fetchall())
    i = i + 1

j = 0
h = 0
ars = []
vars()[str(j)] = ars
element = list(rs)
while j <= 2:
    while h <= 15:
        rp = element[j][h][2]
        ars.append(rp)
        h = h + 1
    else:
        h = 0
    j = j + 1

conn.close()

import csv

#export data in every row
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writerow(ars)
```

I want to get the csv file below,

[image]

That is, assign the first row to ars(0), the second row to ars(1), and the third one to ars(2), and I have used **vars()[str(j)] = ars** to make **variable name ars(j)** increase in while loop, but my output is only in the first row,

[image]

(parts of view)

Where should I modify in my script？

I am working with python 2.7.6 and pyscripter under Windows 8.1 x64. Feel free to give me any suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: Aside: `vars()[str(j)] = ars` -- Who taught you that?  Maybe you have an old enemy, who's trying to stunt your understanding of Python and cause your project to fail?

Comment: Heinz, not sure exactly how you're filling `ars` (its a bit hard to follow), but I do know if you call writerow one time, it only writes one row.

Comment: Do you need to loop through each element of ars and call writerow for each element i of ars?

Comment: As soon as u get one row, write it in csv and make `ars` empty.Dont append all the element at once.